# Percent of total row in SQL pivot

Tags: sql-server, pivot, row, percentage, isnull

There are two parts to my problem:

1. PART 1 IS SOLVED. I have a SQL server pivot query that gives me good
   results, but does not TOTAL some rows because of `NULL` values in
   one of the columns.
2. This pivot needs to be % of total row pivot.

Query:

```
SELECT ISNULL([99211], 0),
       ISNULL([99212], 0),
       ISNULL([99213], 0),
       ISNULL([99214], 0),
       ISNULL([99215], 0),
       (ISNULL([99211], 0) + ISNULL([99212], 0) + ISNULL([99213], 0) + ISNULL([99214], 0) + ISNULL([99215], 0)) AS Total
FROM
(
    SELECT MONTH(c.ClaimServiceDate) AS MOS,
           t.[ProcedureCode],
           ISNULL(CONVERT(INT, t.NumberofCharges), 0) AS Charges
    FROM [EIPODS].[Athena].[claim] c
        INNER JOIN [EIPODS].[Athena].[transactions] t
            ON c.claimID = t.claimID
    WHERE c.ClaimServiceDate
    BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-09-30'
) t
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Charges)
    FOR t.[ProcedureCode] IN ([99211], [99212], [99213], [99214], [99215])
) AS pivot_table
ORDER BY MOS;
```

EDIT: At the suggestion of Alex (below in comment) - I enclosed total in line 1 into `ISNULL` and that eliminated 0 in Total.

Currently Shows:

```
MOS    99211    99212    TOTAL  
----
1      20      30    **50**  
2      0    40       **40**
```

Needs to show:

```
MOS    99211    99212    TOTAL  
----
1      40%      60%     **100%**  
2      0%       100%    **100%**
```

Data:
Transaction Table: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAB5i.png)

Claims Table:
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbDtO.png)

Comment: Have you tried adding `ISNULL` to top level `SELECT` i.e. instead of `SELECT *`, do SELECT ISNULL( [99211], 0 ) ....`?

Comment: Could you share your sample data.. that will helpful for everyone

Comment: Changed top Select to this:    Select *,(ISNULL([99211],0) +ISNULL([99212],0)+ISNULL([99213],0)+ISNULL([99214],0)+ISNULL([99215],0)) as Total
FROM....etc  This eliminated Null in total, but left it in the pivoted data.

Comment: You can't do `select *`.  You need `select isnull([99211],0), isnull([99212],0), ...` in addition to the isnull's in the total line.

Answer (score 0):

For the percent of the total row, I would use an outer select (for readability) like so:

```
SELECT t.[99211] / t.Total AS [99211],
       t.[99212] / t.Total AS [99212],
       t.[99213] / t.Total AS [99213],
       t.[99214] / t.Total AS [99214],
       t.[99215] / t.Total AS [99215],
       t.Total / t.Total
FROM
(
    SELECT pivot_table.MOS,
           ISNULL([99211], 0) AS [99211],
           ISNULL([99212], 0) AS [99212],
           ISNULL([99213], 0) AS [99213],
           ISNULL([99214], 0) AS [99214],
           ISNULL([99215], 0) AS [99215],
           (ISNULL([99211], 0) + ISNULL([99212], 0) + ISNULL([99213], 0) + ISNULL([99214], 0) + ISNULL([99215], 0)) AS Total
    FROM
    (
        SELECT MONTH(c.ClaimServiceDate) AS MOS,
               t.[ProcedureCode],
               ISNULL(CONVERT(INT, t.NumberofCharges), 0) AS Charges
        FROM [EIPODS].[Athena].[claim] c
            INNER JOIN [EIPODS].[Athena].[transactions] t
                ON c.claimID = t.claimID
        WHERE c.ClaimServiceDate
        BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-09-30'
    ) t
    PIVOT
    (
        SUM(Charges)
        FOR t.[ProcedureCode] IN ([99211], [99212], [99213], [99214], [99215])
    ) AS pivot_table
) t
ORDER BY t.MOS;
```

You will have to format the numbers based on your preferences but this should give you the %/Total.